# Stock Market with Graph Plotting (PHP Jquery or any)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, dojo, cometd

I have received a project which to do "Stock Market" but I don't know which method that I shall do with? Anyone can recommend or give me some suggestion to point me out? First of all it is Web based and free of course. Not in flash also. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Eric! Your question is very broad and I don't think It can be answered here. What you need to do is find a pencil and paper and start planing your project yourself. Then if you have specific question come back to SO and ask them. Have fun!

Comment: An honest (imo) question by a guy (not a native English speaker) who is overwhelmed, as any finance-markets neophyte would be, and needs a few pointers to launch himself. I wonder if his question really deserved to be closed. Yes, it's overly broad but could easily have been made sharper, I believe, in a couple of iterations. I'm just a newb here but still this treatment makes me uncomfortable.

Comment: @Pete Wilson: it can be a bit harsh here like that, but in fairness the question was left open long enough for him to get several useful replies. Truly bad questions tend to be closed within minutes, so that's a sign that this one wasn't actually considered *that* bad. And of course he's still welcome to return with more specific questions once he's had a chance to digest the help he's been given so far. BTW, the best place to comment on things like that is on the SO meta site (see the link at the top of the page); if you want to make a point about the site, that's where to do it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into [gRaphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).

It's a cross-browser vector-graphics based javascript graphing library.

hope that helps.

Comment: This library is superb in plotting graph now have to know how to do client and server, push and pull

Answer (score 3):

Since you've mentioned dojo and it sounds like you're in a very early planning stage, perhaps [the lightstreamer demo app](http://www.lightstreamer.com/demo/DojoDemo/) can give you some ideas. The demo uses the DojoX Grid and DojoX Charting to display the events generated by the Lightstreamer Server (some sort of real time stock value server) in both textual and graphical forms.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a stock example using Dojo, http://persevere.sitepen.com/stocker.html

You can view the source of the page and see how it is set up.

Also more info on Dojo charts here:
http://dojotoolkit.org/grids-charts

Answer (score 0):

I'm a huge fan of **[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/)**, which I've used to plot stock options. The  **[programmer's book](http://tinyurl.com/4yxto8x)** has all the right details with no useless extras.

I like Gnuplot particularly well because it lets me put a lot of the plotting burden on the server when I want to.

HTH